# Can the dimensions of header area of JXTaskPane be changed?

Tags: java, swingx, dimension, jxtaskpane

I am using JXTaskPane component. I want to know whether one can change the dimensions of the top part of the task pane i.e. the area where title of the task pane is displayed. If yes, please let me know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, that's not supported: the "top area" is part of the Border which is installed deeply inside the ui delegate. You might consider to file an enhancement issue in SwingX' issue tracker.